# Rails accessing parent model ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:
- User
- Listing
- Review

Users can have many listings and Users can have many reviews.

They are nested like this:

```
  resources :users do
      resource :listings
      resource :reviews
  end
```

I am trying to create a form which creates a new Review. I have the review page located at:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1/reviews/new
```

Which I want to create a new review for user #1.

What I need to do is get that :id (#1 in this case) into my controller and I am not sure how. Currently my reviews_controller.rb is blank as follows:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

end
```

I am unsure what needs to be included in the new function to get the :id of the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean get the current user?
you can do this to get the user

```
user_id = params[:user_id] # this will be 1 in this case
# then you can get the user
user = User.find_by_id(user_id)
```

If you always want to get the user, you can use `before_action(or before_filter in Rails3)`, like this:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :prepare_user

  def new
    # now you can use @user
  end

  private
  def prepare_user
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you! I was way over thinking this one.